# Robots.txt returns 404 instead of displaying text

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-urls

## Problem

When trying to request my robots.txt file at website.com/robots.txt, I always receive a 404 error.

## Files

*config > urls.py*

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include, re_path
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from config import views
from django.conf.urls import handler404, handler500, handler403, handler400

handler404 = views.handler404
handler500 = views.handler500

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
    path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    path('', include('pages.urls')),
    path('plants/', include('plants.urls')),
    path('robots.txt',TemplateView.as_view(template_name='robots.txt', content_type='text/plain')), 
]
```

*config > views.py*

```
from django.http import JsonResponse, Http404, HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render

def handler404(request, exception=None):
    return render(request, '404.html', status=404)

def handler500(request):
    return render(request, '500.html', status=500)
```

*templates > robots.txt*

```
User-Agent: *
Disallow: /admin/
Disallow: /accounts/
```

Parts of my folder structure that may be helpful to know

```
project
|
|---config
|   |
|   |---urls.py
|   |---views.py
|
|---templates 
    |
    |---pages
    |   |---about.html
    |   |---contact.html
    |
    |---404.html
    |---robots.txt
```

I've also tried using only `exception` instead of `exception=None` inside of my handler404.

I've tried to move the robots.txt views and urls into my `pages` app with the `robots.txt` within the pages template folder.

I've tried removing the `content_type=text/plain` from the url pattern.

I've read through several different tutorials and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: It is better to turn this _static_ file into the real `STATIC` file in terms of Django. With current approach - please share your *urls.py included before robots.txt or just try moving it up in the pattern list.

Comment: Hi @IvanStarostin, I moved the robots.txt path to the top of my urlpattern list. This fixed my issue! The robots.txt file is now appearing on the /robots.txt URL. If you could please post your comment as an answer, I will happily mark it as the accepted answer! Also, if you know why that worked, I would appreciate an explanation. I searched through the Django Docs on urlpatterns, but I still don't understand why your suggestion fixed my problem. Thank you for your help! I spent days on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of your secondary urls.py files contain too general pattern which catches "robots.txt" thus URL dispatcher never reaches expected pattern declaration in the end of pattern list.

To fix the issue try moving robots pattern **higher** in the pattern list and/or review included urls.py files and make their patterns more specific.

Also please consider making "static" **robots.txt** file truly `STATIC` in terms of Django. Such files are not supposed to be served by Django backend on prod and do not need template engine involved.